# GNU as: Macro use in instruction operands

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, gnu-assembler

Is there anything in GNU as that would allow something like the following?

```
.macro REG
%eax
.endm

addl  REG, %ebx
```

It seems like macro expansion is only allowed in a "full statement" context:

```
0000000000000000 <.text>:
   0:   03 1c 25 00 00 00 00    add    0x0,%ebx

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 2 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND REG
```

So GNU as is treating `REG` as a symbol, not substituting the macro text.  NASM has "inline macros" that can do this:

```
%define REG %eax

addl REG, %ebx
```

Is there some way to get similar behavior in GNU as?

Comment: The NASM preprocessor technically distinguishes between multi-line macros and single-line macros. Mmacros are like as's and smacros are like the C preprocessor's.

Comment: The standard way is to use a separate macro processor on top of `as`, like the C preprocessor (call your file `foo.S` instead of `foo.s` and `gcc -c foo.S` will run it through CPP before `as`.)  Other macro processors include `m4`.

Comment: The ARM version does have a `.req` (register equ) directive but unfortunately it is not supported for x86. Could have been added in a machine independent way, seems like a useful feature to have.

Comment: @Jester The macro text could be anything.  It just happens to be a register name in my example.